# Pact-js e2e example implementation[Issue:Cannot GET /states] MAC OS

Tags: javascript, pact

Need help on solving the above problem 'cannot GET /states' for http:/localhost:8081/states. I have gone through    https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pact-support/zGj8o6snf5c, it is very helpful but did not find the answer.

GitHub Repository URL:https://github.com/pactfoundation/pactjs/tree/master/examples/e2e

I have set up the Pact-js e2e example on my machine OS X EI Captain[10.11].

1. Run the consumer test `./node_modules/.bin/mocha test/consumer.spec.js`
   Got the successful output.

```html
Pact
    when a call to list all animals from the Animal Service is made
      and there are animals in the database
        ✓ returns a list of animals
    when a call to the Animal Service is made to retreive a single animal by ID
      and there is an animal in the DB with ID 1
        ✓ returns the animal
      and there no animals in the database
        ✓ returns a 404
    when interacting with Animal Service
      ✓ should validate the interactions and create a contract
```

2. Publish the tests `node test/publish.js`. Got the successful output.

```html
Pact contract publishing complete!

Head over to https://test.pact.dius.com.au/ and login with
=> Username: dXfltyFMgNOFZAxr8io9wJ37iUpY42M
=> Password: O5AIZWxelWbLvqMd8PkAVycBJh2Psyg1
to see your published contracts.
```

3. Run the consumer and provider api `npm run api`. Got the successful output

```html
Animal Profile Service listening on http://localhost:8081
Animal Matching Service listening on http://localhots:8080
```

4. Run the provider test `./node_modules/.bin/mocha test/provider.spec.js`.Got the error here

```html
1) Uncaught error outside test suite
  Pact Verification
Pact Verification Failed:  Error: /Users/sakshi.rawal/work/pact-js/node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-provider-verifier-darwin/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: unexpected token at 'Cannot GET /states (Faraday::ParsingError)
'
```

Can you please help me in resolving the error on step 4.
Another question on Step 3 is when I click on the link in the output it does not ask for username and password.

Thanks,
Sakshi

Comment: Corrected above steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you double check you have the latest code pulled down? Looks like a transitive depedency shifted which didn't like the existing content type. I patched it the other day.

Comment: Thanks :) I did git pull and it worked fine. Just one thing about the /states and /setup. After step 3 when I hit these endpoints, it says cannot GET /states. Same error is for /suggestions/1,/setup. Does the states and setup is only generated when provider spec is run?

Comment: Correct. They are to setup data fixtures for corresponding client tests that are expecting data to be or not be there

Comment: But when the profile api is running, http://localhost:8081/states gives cannot GET /states.It should give the list of states ?

Comment: /states is only needed for the tests, it's not part of the real API hence it is only declared in the spec

Comment: Thank you so much Matthew for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Step 3 listed above is not necessary, it is simply to test and use the running APIs.

I suspect step 4 is unable to run the provider with the extra endpoints as it is already running on the same port in step 3 hence the failure. This would mean it is unable to find the endpoint /states during the verification process.

Close all processes and then run step 4 and this endpoint should be added, and the tests should pass.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the response.Thanks for the reply @Matthew Fellows Step 4 worked when I close the processes in Step 3. But now the error is: 

`Pact Verification Failed:  Error: /Users/sakshi.rawal/work/pact-js/node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-provider-verifier-darwin/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in parse: 757: unexpected token at 'TypeError: invalid media type<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.parse (/Users/sakshi.rawal/work/pact-js/examples/e2e/node_modules/content-type/index.js:130:11)<br> &nbs".`